# Getting an OAuth access token for packaged app in chrome

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I've created a packaged app for chrome web store which is now published to testers.
I need to implement one time payment via Chrome Web Store Payments.
for this, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/check_for_payment), I need to get OAuth access token.

The problem is that I do not see *OAuth setup link* on my chrome developers dashboard. Thus I can't get it.

In *change pricing* I've already indicated that my app will use Chrome Web Store Payments.
Also I've tried to wait 24 hours...
Also I've tried to unpublish/publish to testers.
nothing helped.

How to get an OAuth access token?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm running into the same problem and it's redonkulous.  Complicated API?  Step 1 impossible.  Thanks Google.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is out of date. This is unfortunate.

You want to use the [identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) to get an access token dynamically.